# Intuition of $ P( X = a) $ for a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, continuity, random-variables, intuition

Let $(\Omega, {\cal B}, P )$ be a probability space, $( \mathbb{R}, {\cal R} )$ the usual
 measurable space of reals and its Borel $\sigma$- algebra, and $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a random variable.

The meaning of $ P( X = a) $ is intuitive when $X$ is a discrete random variable, because it's the definition of the probability mass function. I am not sure if my question makes sense, but how should I think of $ P( X = a) $ when $X$ is a continuous random variable?

Comment: Since $X$ is measurable, $X^{-1}[\{a\}]\in\mathcal{B}$. Therefore we can consider $P(X^{-1}[\{a\}])$, but as you say, by definition $X$ being continuous means that these measurable sets are null for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $P(X=a)$ is still the probability of $X$ taking on the specific value $a$ which just happens to be $0$ when $X$ has a density.

Comment: Think of $[0,1]$ with uniform probability. Since there are  uncountable points, the probability of each must be zero. It makes more sense to look at $P( a<X \le b)$ or $P(X \le b)$.

Comment: This is $\mu(\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) = a\})$. It still might be positive, e.g. if $X$ looks like $|\sin x| + \sin x$. When it is zero, think about it similarly to $\mu([x,x])$, the measure of this set is infinitely small (it is zero...), but if you would take many of them (set not measures), then it would add up to something of positive measure, e.g. $\mu([x,y])$ for $x < y$ (note that you need to take at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ of those).

Comment: relevant? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok/160979

Answer (score -2):

This doesn't need any measure theory.

1. What's the probability of picking 0.5 from the interval [0,1] following a [insert continuous eg uniform] distribution?
2. Can you measure 100% precisely 1.1566672 cm with a ruler?
3. Open Excel/Google Sheets and in two cells simulate values from a continuous distribution eg normal. In a third cell, check whether the values in the two cells are equal. I don't think they will ever be equal.

Comment: I think Excel and Sheets both use some fixed number of bits in the floating-point numbers they use to represent real numbers. So in fact the variates you get out of their "normal distributions" are discrete.

Comment: @PatrickStevens The question is about intuition not precision. Comment still stands?

Comment: Sure, but "I don't think they will ever be equal" is merely an observation that the sample space is huge and your number of samples is tiny, not an observation about the normal distribution.

Comment: @PatrickStevens right anyhoo relevant? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok/160979

Answer (score -2):

Since probability, $\mathbb P$ is a measure, it is generally defined to mimic the notion of a distance in a given set but with extra conditions to capture reality. Intuitively, distance in $3$D is a volume, distance in $2$D is an area, distance in $1$D is length, distance in discrete/counting numbers is the value. If the notion of continuity existed in this setting, we can prove that infinitely cutting a sheet of paper into two to make a line would lead to something too infinitesimal compared to the sheet we started with. This notion is encoded in saying that the measure of a line in $2$D is zero. Similarly, the measure of a sheet in $3$D is zero and the measure of discrete/counting numbers in $1$D is zero. For the sake of intuition, I implicitly assumed that the pre-image of a discrete random variable is discrete, which in general, is not true. For instance, the indicator function of an interval on real line.